# Rust: Async websocket client using websocket-rs, tokio and SSL

Tags: asynchronous, rust, websocket, client, rust-tokio

I'm trying to implement a websocket client using `websocket-rs`. I want some main loop to continuously listen to incoming events, responding to pings and distributing some of the incoming tasks (potentially long-lasting) to some worker threads (say, using a `std::sync::mpsc`). The worker threads will sometimes need to send data back to the server, but it is not clear to me how exactly I should handle this, for the following problems:

- The first approach would just be to split the websocket into receiver/sender part. However, I am using TLS and thus this is not supported
- Another idea would be to have the worker threads send back data to the main thread and have the main thread handle both incoming websocket messages as well as messages from the wroker thread. That would require my main thread to be able to listen to two receivers at the same time (or do busy waiting alternatingly, which I don't want). I found out that there was a `std::select!` macro at some point, but it is unstable and thus also not a good solution.
- So I wanted to go with an async main thread that can handle both incoming and outgoing requests on the websocket simultaneously. I wanted to go for `tokio` and found an example at https://github.com/websockets-rs/rust-websocket/blob/master/examples/async-client.rs. This seems to be outdated and I cannot get this to run with a recent version of rust, I'm getting complaints that `futures::sync::mpsc` does not exist.

Apart from not compiling, that example seems to suit my needs, so I wanted to ask what implementation of `mpsc` was being used in that example, or more general, works here.

If you think it is unreasonable to get that example running, I'm also happy with a pointer in another direction where I can achieve essentially the same thing, i.e. have a websocket client over TLS that can both continuously receive and send messages independent of each other.

Comment: Have you tried tokio-tungstenite? For me this works perfectly even using TLS.

Comment: I did but didn't get far before this question because documentation and examples weren't so great and I was unsure if the async/await framework was what I was looking for. I took a closer look at it again now and it seems to do what I was looking for, so thank you for pointing out that it's actually the right thing.